# I cannot connect Visual Studio to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

[image]

I have tried all the possible solutions as per my perspective but I still not able to connect database. Please reply as early as possible.

Comment: Could you share the config file please.

Comment: sorry but I couldn't find the option like file sharing

Comment: Just paste the file here, without userid/password of connection strings.

Comment: Add "using System.Configuration;" to the namespace declarations.  Make sure web.config has a correct "MyCon" connection string.